# How to define dimensions in fviz_cluster with PAM data?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means, pca

I have a data frame which is divded as samples in rows and variables in columns

Upon doing a PCA:

```
   df.pca <- PCA(df, graph = FALSE, ncp = Inf)
   df.coord <- data.frame(df.pca$ind$coord)
```

and then k-means on my PCA data:

```
   df.kmeans = kmeans(df.coord, 3, nstart = 25)
```

and to visualize cluster formation:

```
   fviz.cluster(object = df.kmeans, data = df.pca)
```

I get a nice graph with the correct dimensions (dim1 75% and dim 2 12% for my data, calculated by PCA).

But if I do the exact same thing with k-medoid algorithm (PAM):

```
   df.pca <- PCA(df, graph = FALSE, ncp = Inf)
   df.coord <- data.frame(flies.todos.pca$ind$coord)
   df.pam = pam(df.coord, 3, nstart = 25)  

   fviz.cluster(object = df.pam, data = df.pca)
```

I get incorrect dimensions (dim1 3.4%, dim 2 3.4%) with the exact same data.

How can I define the dimensions to those of PCA?

I tried:

```
    fviz.cluster(object = df.pam, data = df.coord)
    fviz.cluster(object = df.pam, data = df)
```

with no success, I always get 3.4% dimensions which are not even close to PCA values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after simple exploring I already know the answer.
For pam() function, a PCA is always done automatically. So basically I was doing a PCA on PCA data, which makes no sense at all. 
If you are going to use pam(), or any other algorithm for clustering, check if PCA is done automatically!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
Just you should put in the arguments stand = FALSE

because if is TRUE, data is standardized before principal component analysis
(: